# DB Manager shows a question mark in front of newly created PostGIS layer

Tags: postgis, dbmanager

I have a polygon layer in a PostGIS database with 16 polygons for the states of Germany. I want to create a new layer for the state of Saxonia in the east of Germany, which has also a different coordinate system. I came up with that expression:

```
CREATE TABLE sachsen AS
SELECT
id, ST_Transform (geom, 25833) AS geom, name, bezeichnung, einwohner_2018 
FROM bundeslaender 
WHERE name = 'Sachsen'
```

It seems to work fine. I can drag & drop the newly created layer into QGIS.

But: Why does DB manager show a question mark in front of the newly created layer? What would be a better expression to create the new layer in a better way?

[image]

EDIT: Ok, I added a primary key to the id column and a spatial index in PgAdmin. I also changed the geometry definition so DB manager doesn't show the question mark anymore. I used that expression:

```
ALTER TABLE sachsen 
ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry (Multipolygon,25833);
```

But how could I change my first expression, so I have everything together?

Comment: Do you have a tooltop showing when you mouse over the question mark?

Comment: Please open a new question for your follow up question so everything is nice and well-structure for future people getting stuck with the same issue. You can add your solution to the "question mark" question as an answer to this post.

Comment: Short answer: use `ST_Transform(...)::GEOMETRY(MULTIPOLYGON, 25833)` - Short explanation: it does the same as your `ALTER ... TYPE ...` statement.